Streamlit App Continues Audio Processing After Experiment Termination Button is Clicked
I'm developing a Streamlit application for a voice interaction experiment. The app allows participants to record audio, which is then processed through STT (Speech-to-Text), LangChain for text processing, and TTS (Text-to-Speech). Participants can terminate the experiment at any time using a "Terminate Experiment" button. However, I've encountered an issue where, even after clicking the termination button, the audio processing continues to run.
import streamlit as st
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import json
from stt import STTProcessor
from process import LangChainProcessor
from tts import TTSProcessor
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time

load_dotenv()

st.sidebar.page_link('app.py', label='Start Screen')


# Define constants
DATA_DIR = Path("experiment_data")
DATA_DIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

class ConversationLogger:
    def __init__(self, save_dir=DATA_DIR):
        self.save_dir = Path(save_dir)
        self.save_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        self.logs = []
    
    def initialize_for_participant(self, participant_id):
        self.participant_id = participant_id
        self.log_file = self.save_dir / f"{participant_id}_conversations.json"
        if self.log_file.exists():
            with open(self.log_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                self.logs = json.load(f)
    
    def log_conversation(self, stt_text, tts_text):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        entries = [
            {"timestamp": timestamp, "text": stt_text, "role": "human"},
            {"timestamp": timestamp, "text": tts_text, "role": "assistant"}
        ]
        self.logs.extend(entries)
    
    def save_to_file(self):
        with open(self.log_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(self.logs, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

    def format_for_llm(self):
        """Format conversation logs for LLM input"""
        return "\n".join(
            f"{entry['role']}: {entry['text']}" 
            for entry in self.logs[-10:]  # Use only the last 10 entries
        )

    def get_conversation_history(self):
        """Get complete conversation logs for Streamlit display"""
        return self.logs


def handle_experiment_termination(logger):
    """Handle experiment termination"""
    try:
        # Save final conversation logs
        logger.save_to_file()
        
        # Save termination information
        end_info = {
            "participant_id": st.session_state.participant_id,
            "end_time": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }
        with open(DATA_DIR / f"{st.session_state.participant_id}_end_info.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(end_info, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
        
        # Clear session
        for key in ['participant_id', 'logger']:
            if key in st.session_state:
                del st.session_state[key]
        
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error occurred during experiment termination: {str(e)}")
        return False


def main():
    
    if st.session_state.get('experiment_ended', False):
        st.switch_page("pages/experiment_complete.py")
        return
    
    st.title(" Voice Conversation Experiment")    
    if 'participant_id' not in st.session_state:
        st.warning("⚠️ Participant registration is required.")
        return
 
    experiment_mode = st.radio(
        "Select experiment mode",
        ["Discourse Marker Mode", "Basic Mode"],
        horizontal=True,  # Display horizontally
        label_visibility="collapsed"  # Hide label
    )
   
    # Initialize logger and participant settings
    if 'logger' not in st.session_state:
        logger = ConversationLogger()
        logger.initialize_for_participant(st.session_state.participant_id)
        st.session_state.logger = logger
        
    stt_processor = STTProcessor()
    lang_processor = LangChainProcessor()
    tts_processor = TTSProcessor()
    
    st.write(f"Participant ID: {st.session_state.participant_id}")
    audio_file = st.audio_input("Record audio", key="audio_recorder")
    
    if audio_file and not st.session_state.get("experiment_ended", False):
        if 'experiment_ended' in st.session_state and st.session_state.experiment_ended:
            st.switch_page("pages/experiment_complete.py")
            return
        
        with st.spinner(" Processing audio..."):
            try:
                # STT processing
                audio_bytes = audio_file.read()
                stt_text = stt_processor.transcribe_audio(audio_bytes)
                if not stt_text:
                    st.error("Failed to convert audio to text. Please try again.")                    
                    return
                
                st.success(" Recognized Text")
                st.write(f" {stt_text}")
                
                # LangChain processing
                conversation_history = st.session_state.logger.format_for_llm()
                
                if experiment_mode == "Basic Mode":
                    tts_text = lang_processor.process_text(stt_text, conversation_history, modify=False)
                elif experiment_mode == "Discourse Marker Mode":
                    tts_text = lang_processor.process_text(stt_text, conversation_history, modify=True)
                
                st.info(" AI's Response")
                st.write(f" {tts_text}")
                
                # Log conversation
                st.session_state.logger.log_conversation(stt_text, tts_text)
                
                # TTS processing
                if 'experiment_ended' in st.session_state and st.session_state.experiment_ended:
                    st.switch_page("pages/experiment_complete.py")
                    return
                tts_processor.speak_text(tts_text)
                
            except Exception as e:
                st.error(f"An error occurred during processing: {str(e)}")
    
    # Display conversation logs - use complete history
    st.markdown("---")
    with st.expander("Check current conversation history", expanded=False):
        if 'logger' in st.session_state:
            st.json(st.session_state.logger.get_conversation_history())
    
    with st.expander("End Experiment", expanded=False):
        st.warning("Once the experiment ends, you will no longer be able to continue voice conversations.")
        if st.button("End Experiment", type="primary"):
            # Immediately update session state
            st.session_state.experiment_ended = True
            st.session_state.stop_processing = True  # Additional
            try:
                # Save final conversation logs
                st.session_state.logger.save_to_file()
                
                # Save termination information
                end_info = {
                    "participant_id": st.session_state.participant_id,
                    "end_time": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                }
                with open(DATA_DIR / f"{st.session_state.participant_id}_end_info.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    json.dump(end_info, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
                
                # Clear session
                for key in ['participant_id', 'logger']:
                    st.session_state.pop(key, None)
                
                st.


Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
I attempted to implement asynchronous processing or use session state to prevent audio processing from triggering unnecessarily.
